# How i can find data in array php

Tags: php, mysql, php-7.1

I have data array in php like this,

```
0 => 
  "data" =>
     0 => 
       "id_data": "P-1234",
       "name_data": "data 0 warga 1"
     1 => 
       "id_data": "P-1235",
       "name_data": "data 0 warga 2"
1 =>
  "data" =>
     0 => 
       "id_data": "O-1134",
       "name_data": "data 1 warga 1"
     1 => 
       "id_data": "O-1135",
       "name_data": "data 1 warga 2"
     2 => 
       "id_data": "O-1136",
       "name_data": "data 1 warga 3"
```

How i can find data id_data O-1135 in php?
Thanks you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
        "data" =>[ 
            0 => [ "id_data"=>"P-1234", "name_data"=>"data 0 warga 1"],
            1 => ["id_data"=> "P-1235","name_data"=> "data 0 warga 2"]
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        "data" => [
          0 => ["id_data"=> "O-1134","name_data"=> "data 1 warga 1"],
          1 => ["id_data"=> "O-1135","name_data"=> "data 1 warga 2"],
          2 => ["id_data"=> "O-1136", "name_data"=> "data 1 warga 3"],
         ] 
    ]
];

function find_value_from_arr($arr, $findVal){
    foreach($arr as $childArr){
        if(( $indx = array_search( $findVal, array_column($childArr['data'], 'id_data')) ) !== FALSE){
            return $childArr['data'][$indx]; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
print_r(find_value_from_arr($arr,'O-1135'));
```